# How to convert a string containing a date to a different format?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Consider this string

```
11/12/2010
```

I need to convert this to `20101112`.

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a string to a date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567448/convert-a-string-to-a-date-format)

Comment: Fredrik that question is not mine and even its asked on Oct14 please check.. thanks

Comment: by duplicate, @fredrick refers to the fact the content of both this question and the other are the same, thus the answer provided in the linked question is applicable here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the first is a valid date, and the second is a different representation of the date, the easiest method with the least amount of code for your example is:

```
string newString = DateTime.ParseExact("11/12/2010", "MM/dd/yyyy").ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: I am getting error for first conversion..Trying second one..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string input = "11/12/2010";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(input);
string formattedOutput = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

The above as a one-liner:

```
string formattedOutput = DateTime.Parse("11/12/2010").ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.. problem is very firt time I am getting the value somethign like this 20101112 when I use the above code I will get error.. second time I am getting the value from text box something like this 11/12/2010 bec the date string value I am getting from textgbox

Comment: It appears that Parse doesn't understand the format of the initial string you want to parse. Try parsing that string with ParseExact, passing that method a format specification so that the method can understand the format of the incoming string.